# $\mathbb R[x]/(f)\cong\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I’m trying to use The First Isomorphism Theorem for rings to answer some questions.

I need to show that $$\mathbb R[x]/(f)\cong\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$$ where $f=ax^2+bx+c$ whose discriminant is greater than $0$. I know that all I need to do is define a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb R[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ whose kernel is $(f)$. But I have no intuition with this and just need some guidance

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=a(x-c_1)(x-c_2)$ for $c_1\neq c_2 \in \Bbb R$ (two real distinct roots).

Send $p(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ to $(p(c_1),p(c_2)) \in \Bbb R^2$.

The kernel is $(f)$ as $(x-c_1)|p(x)$ and $(x-c_2)|p(x)$ implies $(x-c_1)(x-c_2) | p(x)$ and so $f(x)|p(x)$ etc.

Comment: What about the factor of $a$ in the last step?

Comment: @Loobear23 that's a unit, so doesn't affect divisibility. If $f(x) | g(x)$ so does $af(x)$ for a unit $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: One approach might involve the fact that evaluation maps are ring homomorphisms. To get $\mathbb{R}^2$ you clearly need to evaluate at *two* points $x \in \mathbb{R}$. What points could these possibly be?